# Mount partitions read only in pantheon-files on ElementaryOS

Tags: mount, elementary-os, pantheon

I've currently dual booted my laptop with windows 8.1 and ElementaryOS Freya. As I've enabled the fast bootup feature in Windows, I can only mount the NTFS Windows partition on ElementaryOS as "read-only". I'm able to mount as read only via terminal. But I want to know if there is way to enable such a feature, that is mount any partition as read only, in "Pantheon files", the default file manager in ElementaryOS.

I was able to do this in Ubuntu which had the "Disk Utility" program via which I was able to set the read only option and "Nautilus", the default the file manager in Ubuntu was successful in mounting the NTFS partition as read only.